# Which is the best datatype to store UUIDs in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, types, binary, uuid, bytea

I am trying to store **UUID**s in a posts table (posts - social media like it doesn't matter), and I would like to know which is the correct way to store **UUID**s in **PostgreSQL**. I have tried to convert them into bytes and store them into **binary**(16) datatype columns in **MySQL**. But I cannot find a similar type in **PostgreSQL** such as **binary**(16) I found only **bytea**. So I need a datatype that will help with the size of the column. Is there anything like **bytea** var-sized?

Comment: There's [`bit(128)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html), but you don't want that.

Comment: Is uuid datatype "ok" in terms of storage in comparison with binary?

Comment: What do you mean by "ok"? With what `binary` are you comparing it? If you're talking about sqlserver, notice [`binary(16)` shouldn't be used there either](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/126446/188406).

Comment: Yes sorry I was not clear, I meant binary(16) of MySQL I need to find a way to make uuids size lighter

Comment: There is no way to make it "lighter". A UUID takes 128 bits or 16 bytes to store, no way around that. (And all of the mentioned data types have this fixed size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the dedicated [`uuid` datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html). Not bytes or bits.